# Virgin Mobile HTC desire 510 root?

Tags: rooting, htc-desire

Has anyone found a solid way to root the VM HTC desire 510? I have search long and hard but haven't found anything substantial. I know the 510 is rootable, and I have found a few tutorials, but they aren't very clear ones. Has anyone written a really solid step by step tutorial for rooting this phone?